# How to set-up mouseemu on Debian

Tags: debian, mouse

I own an iBook running Debian Sid and would like to configure `mouseemu` to emulate a mouse wheel using the right `Apple`-key and the trackpad.

It seems that I can get away wit the `-scroll` option of `mouseemu` however I am not sure how to arrange my system so that `mouseemu` is run automatically after each reboot.

Furthermore, I configured middle and right button emulation by adding the statements

```
dev.mac_hid_mouse.mouse_button_emulation=1
dev.mac_hid_mouse.mouse_button2_keycode=68
dev.mac_hid_mouse.mouse_button3_keycode=69
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and I could not determine if these settings are compatible with `mouseemu` or not.

Answer (score -1):

Write

SCROLL="-scroll 125"

into etc/default/mouseemu. 125 is the keycode for the Apple key.